# machine.config path

Tags: c#, .net

How do I get the path to the machine.config from a .Net application? It should automatically get the correct path based on the .Net version of the app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.SystemConfigurationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeenvironment.systemconfigurationfile.aspx) should give you that value..